# Cannot handle Unhandled Promise Rejection using try-catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, ytdl, unhandled-promise-rejection

Hi I just downloaded ytdl-core module and I am encountering a Promise Rejection which I cannot handle! Can anyone please help?

```
app.get("/getaudio", async (req, res) => {
  const videoID = req.query.v;
  const quality = req.query.q;
  try {
    ytdl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, {
      quality: quality,
      filter: "audioonly",
    }).pipe(res);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send("Encountered Error: " + e.message);
  }
});
```

Here is the code
I wrapped the whole thing in a try catch block but still cannot handle the Promise Rejection
Any pointers is Appreciated.

Here is the stacktrace if this helps:

```
(node:1752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No such format found: asdasd
    at Object.exports.chooseFormat (D:\Code and Other Things\YTAudioStream\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\format-utils.js:168:11)
    at downloadFromInfoCallback (D:\Code and Other Things\YTAudioStream\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\index.js:86:26)
    at D:\Code and Other Things\YTAudioStream\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\index.js:20:5
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I know I provided an invalid quality param and that is intentional, I want to handle this rejection in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ytdl` returns a readable stream and handling stream errors are a little tricky. You need to use `.on()` to detect errors, So:

```
ytdl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, {
  quality: quality,
  filter: "audioonly",
}).on('error', (err) => console.log(err)).pipe(res);
```

But if you really want to use try-catch then I suppose you can throw it yourself:

```
ytdl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, {
  quality: quality,
  filter: "audioonly",
}).on('error', (err) => throw err).pipe(res);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Did not know Readable Stream Emits an Error Event rather than throwing the error! I learnt something new today :)